# page change command not working in a definition within a class

Tags: python, tkinter

**CONTEXT**: I am programming a word game where a 3x3 grid with 5 letter words is displayed to the user and then the grid changes and 1 word is removed and replaced. The user is then asked to input which word has been removed and which one has substituted it.

**PROBLEM**: in the class where the user has to enter the words, my selection statement in my validation def within the class is working correctly however it is not changing page.

code example:

```
self.submit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="submit", command = self.validate1)
self.submit_button.grid(row=5, column=2)


def validate1(self):
       word = (self.entry.get()+"\n")
       print("input",word) #printed for testing purposes 
       print(sub) #printed for testing purposes
if word == sub:
        lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage)
else:
        print("incorrect")
```

**Note**: the validation works fine as I tested out with just printing incorrect in the shell, however when I use lambda to change page nothing happens, I also do not receive any error
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: what is `sub` supposed to be?

Comment: Oh sorry, sub is meant to be the variable for the word that has been substituted, i have just passed it from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.controller = controller

```
if word == sub:
       self.controller.show_frame(StartPage)
```

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` merely *create* a command, it doesn't run it. You don't need to use `lambda` at all, just call the function directly:

```
if word == sub:
    controller.show_frame(StartPage)
```

Comment: I have added your changes however i am getting an error that controller is not defined which is most likely to do with my parameters in the def, atm it is just self do i need to add anything? Thank you once again in advance